# Find the expected number of hours all 512 people suffer

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, expected-value

> In a crowded room with 512 people, there are 9 different types of blood antigens. Each person has a blood type corresponding to a distinct subset of the antigens; the remaining of the antigens are foreign to them.

> Matt the Mosquito flies around the room, picks a subset of the people uniformly at random, and bites the chosen people in a random order. After biting a person, Matt stores a bit of any antigens that person had. A person bitten while Matt had k blood antigens foreign to him or her will suffer for k hours. What is the expected total suffering of all 512 people in hours?

Let $n=9$ be the number of different antigens.

I think the linearity of expectation could be useful. Note that each person is bitten with probability 1/2. Consider a person P and an antigen a foreign to him/her. Assuming P has been bitten, it would be useful to find the probability P will suffer due to a. There are $2^{n-1}$ people with antigen a. But I'm not sure how to find the probability P will suffer due to a. Though with this given probability, it should be possible to use linearity over pairs (P,a) where P is a person and a is an antigen foreign to that person.

Comment: I suggest:  do this for a smaller power of $2$ than $2^9$.  Work it out for $2^n$, $n≤4$, say.  If nothing else, that will let you test whatever formula you eventually find.

Comment: This problem seems tricky to me.  Assume that Person-1 is bitten, and that Person-1 is not immune to Antigen-1.  You can reason that of the $256$ people in the room that you expect to have Antigen-1, $128$ of them will be bitten.  However, it is unclear to me whether you can conclude from this that Person-1's expectation of suffering from Antigen-1 specifically is $\dfrac{128}{129}.$  That is, of the $256$ people bitten by Matt, you might have (for example) that $129$ of them have Antigen-1, while only $127$ of them have Antigen-2.  ...see next comment

Comment: So, assuming that Person-1 is not immune to either Antigen-1 or Antigen-2, this would imply that Person-1's expected combined suffering from Antigen-1 and Antigen-2, based on the $(129,127)$ assumption would be $$\frac{129}{130} + \frac{127}{128} \color{red}{\neq} 2 \times \frac{128}{129}.$$  ...see next comment

Comment: Because I am insecure that my intuition might lead to an inaccurate answer, I would consider the approach that the probability is $$\frac{\binom{512}{k}}{2^{512}},$$ that Matt bites $k$ people.  Then, of these $k$ people, there must be an element $~a \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,k\}~$ such that exactly $~a~$ of these $~k~$ people have Antigen-1, and $~(k-a)~$ of these people do not have Antigen-1.  So, I would compute $p(a,k)$, which is the probability that exactly $a$ of the bitten people have Antigen-1, under the assumption that $k$ people were bitten.  ...see next comment

Comment: This (**very ugly, very inelegant, but doable**) approach would allow me to compute all of the hours of suffering specifically caused by Antigen-1.  Then, I would have to *ponder* whether Linearity of Expectation can be applied to each Antigen, so that I could simply take the Antigen-1 computation and multiply it by $9$.  Personally, my intuition in this area is no where near developed enough to have any confidence that I can determine when the Linearity of Expectation shortcut can be applied.  This is a tricky problem.

Answer (score 1):

I agree: linearity of expectation is a good approach here.

## Notation setup

I'm going to treat the problem size as a parameter: Let's say there are $N$ types of antigens and $2^N$ people in the room. (Your statement is the special case $N=9$.)

Let $S$ be the total suffering across all people, $S_p$ be the total suffering for person $p$, and $S_{p,a}$ be the amount of suffering of person $p$ from antigen $a$. Let $P_{p,a}$ be the probability that person $p$ ends up suffering from antigen $a$. Thus $S_{p,a}$ will always be $1$ (with probability $P_{p,a}$) or $0$ otherwise.

## Reducing using linearity of expectation

You're asking for $E[S]$, and we can write
$$\begin{align}
E[S]
&= E\left[ \sum_{p} S_p \right] \\
&= E\left[ \sum_{p,a} S_{p,a} \right] \\
&= \sum_{p,a} E[S_{p,a}] \\
&= \sum_{p,a} P_{p,a}
\end{align}$$
where I've used linearity to pull the sum outside the $E$.

## Solving the reduced problem

Opening comment: Biting a uniform random subset of people is the same as flipping an independent fair coin to decide whether to bite each person. I find the second interpretation much more useful in terms of intuition and I recommend readers think about it this way.

With the L.o.E. reduction in mind, the problem is reduced to finding $P_{p,a}$.
If person $p$ already has antigen $a$, or if $p$ never gets bitten, then they certainly won't suffer from $a$. So let's focus on the case where person $p$ does not have antigen $a$ and does get bitten. In that case, there are $2^{N-1}$ other carriers who do have antigen $a$. Some number of those carriers will be bitten; the probability of exactly $k$ carriers being bitten is $\binom{2^{N-1}}{k} / 2^{\left(2^{N-1}\right)}$.

Given that exactly $k$ carriers are bitten, the probability of person $p$ catching disease $a$ is exactly $\frac{k}{k+1}$, since if we ignore everyone except those $k$ carriers and $p$, they'll escape the disease only if they are the first one bitten out of these $k+1$ people.

The probability that person $p$ gets bitten is $\frac 1 2$, so we can write (assuming $p$ does not start out with antigen $a$)
$$\begin{align}
P_{p,a} &= \frac 1 2 \left[ \frac{1}{2^{\left(2^{N-1}\right)}} \sum_{k=0}^{2^{N-1}} \binom{2^{N-1}}{k} \frac{k}{k+1} \right] \\
&= \frac 1 2 \left(\frac{1}{2^{\left(2^{N-1}\right)}} \right)
\left(\frac{1 - 2^{\left(2^{N-1}\right)} + 2^{\left(2^{N-1}\right)} 2^{N-1}}{2^{N-1}+1}\right) \\
&= \frac 1 2 \left[ \frac{1}{2^{\left(2^{N-1}\right)}\left(2^{N-1} + 1\right)} + \frac{2^{N-1}-1}{2^{N-1}+1} \right]
\end{align}$$

I'm omitting proof of the step where I replace the $\sum_k$ with a closed form. It can be shown by combinatorics or by induction, but easiest is by WolframAlpha. I used [this query](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Simplify%5BSum%5B1%2F2%5Em*Binomial%5Bm%2C%20k%5D*k%2F%28k%20%2B%201%29%2C%20%7Bk%2C%200%2C%20m%7D%5D%5D) and got these results:

[image]

Anyway, now we can put the subanswers together to answer the full problem. For each $a$, exactly $2^{N-1}$ people start out with the disease (hence have no chance of catching it) and the other $2^{N-1}$ people start without the disease (hence their chance of catching it is given by the messy formula above). So our final answer is:

$$\begin{align}
E[S] &= \sum_a \sum_p P_{p,a} \\
&= \sum_a 2^{N-1} \frac 1 2 \left[ \frac{1}{2^{\left(2^{N-1}\right)}\left(2^{N-1} + 1\right)} + \frac{2^{N-1}-1}{2^{N-1}+1} \right] \\
&= \boxed{N 2^{N-2} \left[ \frac{1}{2^{\left(2^{N-1}\right)}\left(2^{N-1} + 1\right)} + \frac{2^{N-1}-1}{2^{N-1}+1} \right]}
\end{align}$$

## Intuition and double-checking

Intuitively, unless $N$ is tiny, if person $p$ starts out without antigen $a$ and gets bitten then I would pretty much expect them to catch $a$. Like if $N = 100$, there are just so so many infected people that had a chance to get bitten first; it seems pretty unlikely that person $p$ will avoid infection. This is borne out by the boxed formula above: all the stuff inside $\left[ \cdots \right]$ will be pretty close to $1$ for large $N$ (or really for any $N$ bigger than like $2$ or $3$), so the answer will be pretty close to $N 2^{N-2}$ which is what we'd get if every bitten person catches every disease they don't start with.

We can also double-check the exact formula using a Python simulation. I used this code:

```
# use the formula we derived
def exact(N):
    return N*2**(N - 2)*(1/(2**(2**(N - 1))*(2**(N - 1) + 1)) + (2**(N - 1) - 1)/(2**(N - 1) + 1))

import random
# simulate a bunch of times to get an approximate answer
def sim(N, NUM_TRIALS):
    total_suffering = 0
    for trial_num in range(NUM_TRIALS):
        current_suffering = 0

        # decide who gets bitten
        bitten = []
        for p in range(2**N):
            if random.randint(0,1) == 1: bitten.append(p)
        # random bite order
        random.shuffle(bitten)
        
        diseases = 0  # track which diseases the fly is carrying
        for p in bitten:
            diseases |= p  # fly catches all of p's diseases
            current_suffering += diseases.bit_count() - p.bit_count()  # suffer 1 hour per disease that the fly has but p didn't have before
        total_suffering += current_suffering
    return total_suffering / NUM_TRIALS

for n in range(0, 10):
    ex = exact(n)
    si = sim(n, 10**5)
    print(n, ex, si, sep='\t')
```

and I got these printouts:

```
0   0.0 0.0
1   0.125   0.12479
2   0.8333333333333333  0.83008
3   3.675   3.67416
4   12.45138888888889   12.44043
5   35.29415355009191   35.31057
6   90.1818181824955    90.21302
7   217.1076923076923   217.13148
8   504.06201550387595  504.04763
9   1143.035019455253   1142.75689
```

That's enough accuracy to make me feel mostly convinced that the formula is right. I also tried running with more trials for some of the smaller $N$ values and confirmed that the simulation results got a little closer to the exact answers.

## Additional confirmation: Full brute force for small $N$

A skeptical commenter suggested using a full brute force solver to confirm the exact answer for small $N$. Here's some Python code:

```
import itertools
import math
import fractions
def count_suffering(bitten):
    suffering = 0
    diseases = 0
    for p in bitten:
        diseases |= p  # fly catches all of p's diseases
        suffering += diseases.bit_count() - p.bit_count()  # suffer 1 hour per disease that the fly has but p didn't have before
    return suffering

def bruteforce(N):
    total_suffering = fractions.Fraction(0)
    for num_bitten in range(2**N+1):
        for bitten in itertools.combinations(range(2**N), num_bitten):
            current_suffering = fractions.Fraction(0)
            for bitten_ordered in itertools.permutations(bitten):
                current_suffering += count_suffering(bitten_ordered)
            total_suffering += current_suffering / math.factorial(num_bitten)
    bitten_options = 2**(2**N)  # total number of subsets we could have picked
    expected_suffering = total_suffering / bitten_options
    return expected_suffering

for n in range(4): print(bruteforce(n))
```

and the output:

```
0
1/8
5/6
147/40
```

I've confirmed that these are the same as my formula's output for $N=0, 1, 2, 3$.
If I really cared I could code this in C++ and then the $N=4$ case would also finish in a reasonable amount of time. I'm not bothering because I honestly just feel sufficiently convinced that the formula is correct already, and I think Python is a better language to post here since more people can read it.

## Bonus notes

The exact answer to the specific version you asked ($N = 9$) is:
$$\frac{265742844799640668497095410594938748523254614807645094470555155298160632523653129}{232488804171798923623888618337756189986643641086481444985473430390888080605184}$$

Viewing the answer as a function $S(N)$, it turns out that $\tilde S(N) = N 2^{N-2} - N$ is an extremely close approximation. The first several values of $S(N) - \tilde S(N)$ are:

```
0   0.
1   0.625
2   0.833333
3   0.675
4   0.451389
5   0.294154
6   0.181818
7   0.107692
8   0.0620155
9   0.0350195
10  0.0194932
```

So for most practical purposes you'd be fine using that much simpler formula instead.

Comment: "The probability that person p gets bitten is $~\dfrac{1}{2}$" : strangely enough, I think that this is invalid, since you have committed to analysis based on associating a certain probability to the event that exactly $~k~$ people are bitten.  **Inside** this case, when $~k~$ people are bitten, the probability that Person-1 is bitten is $$\frac{k}{2^N}.$$

Comment: @user2661923 I'm not talking about the probability of $k$ *people* being bitten, but rather about the probability of $k$ *carriers of antigen* $a$ being bitten. That's what creates the discrepancy between our formulas: I have $2^{N-1}$ (the number of people carrying antigen $a$) where you have $2^N$ (the total number of people). Thanks again for your careful checking though!

Comment: I was responding to your first comment, but my response addresses your second comment. Person $p$ being bitten is independent from how many $a$-carriers are bitten, since $p$ was assumed not to be an $a$-carrier. (Probably this is clear to you though, and the misunderstanding in my comment above would make you satisfied.)

Comment: I think my math is correct, at least on the points you're bringing up. I'm happy to explain a bit more in the comments (or maybe edit the post if the discussion brings up points that I think could likely help others too). I would suggest against deleting your comments even if you later think they're wrong, since someone else might go down the same wrong path; personally I'd rather just make a later comment explaining why you were wrong before, so that a later reader could benefit from what you learned.

Comment: No, I deleted my comments, which I think is best.  Initially, I strongly suspected that you had made a mistake.  Now that you have explained your thinking, given my lack of intuition around linearity of expectation problems, I make it **at least**  50-50 that I am wrong, and that you are right.  Given that, I don't think it is appropriate to leave my comments.

Comment: @user2661923 Sure. Quick note about the last one you deleted: biting a uniform random subset of people turns out to be the same distribution as if we just flipped an independent fair coin to decide whether to bite each person. The second formulation makes it easier to see that my statement about "$p$ is bitten" being independent from "exactly $k$ carriers of $a$ are bitten" is true.

Comment: The one thing that I would recommend is that you sanity-check by assuming (for example) that $N=3$, and that there are $8$ people and $256$ possible subsets.  I would assign the  8 antigens so that the $256$ people represent all $256$ cases of how the antigens could be randomly assigned.  Then, I would check each of the $256$ subsets one at a time.  For each subset, I would perform the simulation $8!$ times, providing a separate ordering of the people to each simulation.  This would represent the acid test of whether your formulas are correct.

Comment: Re my last comment, if your computer program balks because you are overloading it with cases, a valid *cpu-shortcut* is to complicate your program.  For each of the $256$ subsets, count how many people in that subset will be bitten.  Assuming that there are $k$ people bitten, in that subset, then you only have to repeat that particular subset $k!$ times.

Comment: Also, since the point of the sanity check is to verify your formula for general values of $N$, you want to stick with large integers (i.e. exact calculations) for all the fractions.  I know that Java (for example) has a BigInteger class, and I imagine that there are similar capabilities for C and Python.

Comment: @user2661923 I edited my post to add brute force code for $N=0, 1, 2, 3$ as you suggest.

Comment: +1 : Very nice answer.